# Accessing member parent function to child

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

The problem is I have a Sort parent class (Sorter) and many children( merge,bubble,quick)

What I m trying to do is to access the function  "runOnce" which is a function in parent class.

**Main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    fstream Data;
    Data.open("Test.txt",ios::in|ios::out);

    Sorter<int>* bubble = new BubbleSort<int>;
      Sorter<int>* quick = new QuickSort<int> ;
    Sorter<int>* merge = new MergeSort<int> ;
    vector<int> list;
     while(!Data.eof())
    {
      int temp; 
     Data >> temp;
      list.push_back(temp);
    }
    Sorter<int>::runOnce(bubble, list);
    Data.close();
}
```

**Sorter.cpp**

```
#ifndef SORTER_H
#define SORTER_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Sorter {
    public:
        Sorter(){};
        virtual void sort(vector<T>&, int, int) = 0;
        double runOnce(Sorter<T>&, vector<T>&);

};

#endif // SORTER_H
```

but I m getting an error in main in line of

> Sorter::runOnce(bubble, list);

it says:

> no matching function for call to 'sorter::
>   runOnce(Sorter*&, std:: vector < int , std :: allocator < int > > &)

And I tried to change it to be

```
bubble->Sorter->runOnce(bubble, list);
```

and it said

> invalid use of Sorter< int >::Sorter

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you want call `runOnce(bubble, list);` `runOnce` must be static function

Answer (score 1):

The function takes a `Sorter&`, not a `Sorter*&`. Dereference the pointer when passing it in, e.g:
`Sorter<int>::runOnce(*bubble, list);`

Comment: it says cannot call member function 'double Sorter <T>::runOnce (Sorter<T>&,std:: vector<t>&) (with T= int )' without object

Comment: Call it through the object (`bubble->runOnce(*bubble, list);`) or make `runOnce` static so it can be called via the class.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it with making runOnce a function in the main and calling it and it solved everything. Also I used the header files of the parent class in the children because I was using the cpp file.